# Deleting the physical file from disk causes SQL FileStream to throw an exception for the entire table

Tags: sql-server

We're doing a bit of research about possibly implementing SQL FileStream as our file storage solution.

When you insert a record, it stores the file in the same location as the FileGroup path, so we wanted to see what happens if we delete the file without telling SQL. When I do a select on the table, it returns the error:

```
A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server.
```

I can understand that I've messed things up, but it seems a little silly to me that the entire table is now inaccessible. My concern is that if something had to happen in production to one of the files, then not being able to recover anything is obviously a massive problem.

What's happening here?

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server maintains an exclusive lock on files during operation, and assumes it can continue to do so. It also requires that files are not modified outside of it's control, particularly with respect to 'write ahead logging'.

To put your question in another context: I go and hex edit data in a table, I destroy one row and make the 8kb page it sits on inaccessible because when read from disk it no longer passes the CRC check. When I do a SELECT * FROM table, if I touch that data-page on disk, the query will bomb out just as you've observed with your filestream.

The moral of the story is that SQL Server makes specific promises to clients in terms of ACID properties. It will cease and desist it's work any time it becomes aware the rules of it's known universe have changed. Another good example is deleting one of the files in a FILEGROUP - where you *know* personally you've emptied the file - SQL Server can't be sure until it sees the file that it doesnt need to be there to ensure consistency.

In short: Don't delete files from SQL Servers path.

Comment: As an additional note, while I appreciate your concerns about recovery - bear in mind the only supported way to back up and restore filestream data is via the T-SQL backup API. You aren't expected to get a succesful operation when you backup, restore or change files outside SQL in ways that are not described verbatim in the transaction log.